# Process files recursively using bash

Tags: bash, file, recursion

I currently have a small script that processes all files in a directory. I would like this to also recursively process all files in the subfolder. Any thoughts on how to do this?
My current code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in ./input/*
do
   do_something "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find input/ -type f -exec do_something {} \;
```

From the `man` page:

> The find utility recursively descends the directory tree for each path listed, evaluating an expression (composed of the `primaries` and `operands` listed below) in terms of each file in the tree.

For clarity, here's some more detail from the `man` page about `exec` and `{}`:

> -exec utility [argument ...] ;
>
> True if the program named utility returns a zero value as its exit status.
>
> Optional arguments may be passed to the utility.  The expression must
>   be terminated by a semicolon (`;`).  If you invoke find from a shell
>   you may need to quote the semicolon if the shell would otherwise treat
>   it as a control operator.  If the string `{}` appears anywhere in
>   the utility name or the arguments it is replaced by the pathname of the current file.  Utility will be executed from the directory from which find was executed. Utility and arguments are not subject to the further expansion of shell patterns and constructs.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: `find input/ -type f -exec do_something "$file" {} \;`

would this code do what I wanted then?

Comment: Hi. `{}` is a placeholder for the matching filepath, so you don't need to specify a variable.

Answer (score 4):

In `bash` 4, you can use the `**` pattern, which matches 0 or more directories in a path.

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in ./input/**/*
do
   do_something "$file"
done
```